# JavaFX 2.x in desktop development?

Tags: java, desktop, javafx

I have to find technology for new desktop application on Java only.
I don't want use swing, but I can't find good and perspective alternatives. 
I know about JavaFX, but I have strong requirements: It must look good, not roughly on linux, windows and macOx. Does JavaFX work fine on each of this platforms? And which a big troubles can I find in using JavaFX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using FX in desktop development. It's great, but far away from being perfect. Also there's no Linux version at this moment, as for Mac, it's only beta 2.1 (which i'm using right now). The biggest thing that annoys me is freezes. U can download visual editor right [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html#sb)

BTW Gosling [belives](http://www.zdnet.com.au/gosling-rebirth-of-java-on-desktops-339277112.htm) that FX would become more usefull in desktop dev than in RIA development

Comment: I took linux version from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html. But now I have some troubles with set up SDK... Can U tell something about behavior complete FX application on Linix or Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse's [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) should definitely be considered. It supports all three platforms mentioned and IMO is nicer to use than Swing.